# How to create per-function memory profile of a multithreaded C++ program?

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind, massif

**Problem:**

I have a multi-threaded C++ program, which handles quite some data (a few GB). At some point, my program runs out of main memory, which is something that I want to avoid. Theoretically, this should not happen, since the amount of data that this program analyzes is still much less than my main memory.

**Assumed problem root:**

My guess is that at some point I am passing all of that data by value to some function or some similar stupid mistake. This than ramps up my memory usage and I run out of main memory.

**How can I find the code that causes the problem?**

I would like to profile the memory usage of my program on a per-function basis. So the outcome should be something like (where both `f` and `g` are functions):

```
f    used 10% of total memory used
g    used  1% of total memory used
```

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485967/how-much-memory-does-a-function-use), I had a look at [massif by Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html). Looks like an amazing tool, but `valgrind --tool=massif ./myProgram` takes forever (even if I reduce the amount of data substantially).

**Question:**

What tool can I use to find the "bug" in my source code? I am looking for something that does not take forever to run, but still gives me the insight I need. I am also willing to do this programmatically by somehow changing my source code.

**Env:**

Compiler: Clang 9

OS: RHEL

C++: std=17

Comment: I use a simple object counter by type, keeping track of how many have been created, the "high water" maximum that had been alive at a given point of time, then dump out that information at the end of main to a file.

Comment: Windows have very nice debug heap - each allocation has 32B header (_CrtMemBlockHeader) with linked list - would tell, in case you can recognize threads, it can help too and as you can see here https://github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory/blob/master/wininc/crtdbg.h there is also similar alternative (never used that one - used VS after exit app or valgrind in UX). And in case you can allocate something small, move -32B back (or -- on header ptr) and get first or last element during some execution.

Comment: @Eljay nice idea in general. But here it is about handling data. So its more like `std::vector<...> v` has 100.000 elements or so. Thats one object, but if you pass that around, things might break

Comment: @Tom I am on Linux. I will add that in my question

Comment: Dr. Memory operates on unmodified application binaries running on Windows, Linux, Mac, or Android on commodity IA-32, AMD64, and ARM hardware.

Comment: @Tom thanks, I will have a look :)